# React Native FCM not working

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using this package https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm
I complete the installation process. The project is working. But every time I turn it on project. I am working `./gradlew clean` on console. Other than that, I get the following error when I run

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can delete build folder, and recompile project again.

Comment: What was the reason of "Build failed" this time?

Comment: The same thing happens when I turn it off and back on again

Comment: @ahmet just delete folder build in path, C:\reactnative\moneva\android\app\build.

Comment: if i am working ./gradlew clean, already delete android/app/build directory